# How do I use the result of a useEffect fetch in a subsequent fetch?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I can't figure out how to pass a field's data from one useEffect fetch query (using GROQ) to a second useEffect fetch query using a REST API with URL parameters.

```
  const [airline, setAirline] = useState(null);
  const [airport, setAirport] = useState(null);
  const { slug } = useParams();

  const url = "https://aviation-edge.com/v2/public/airportDatabase?key={myKeyHere}&codeIataAirport=";

  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient
      .fetch(
        `*[slug.current == $slug]{
          ...
          hubIataCode,
          ...
        }`,
        { slug }
      )
      .then((data) => setAirline(data[0]))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, [slug]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${url}${airline.hubIataCode}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setAirport(data));
  }, []);
```

Perhaps the two need combining?

To my surprise there isn't much information on using data from the first API call on the second with useEffect, or perhaps I can't word my search correctly.

Comment: the 1st ```useEffect``` changes the value of ```airline```, so maybe you can add ```airline``` as dependency of the 2nd```useEffect```, which will trigger the 2nd ```useEffect``` when the 1st ```useEffect``` is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 - Add `airline` as dependency to the 2nd `useEffect` and bail out if it's `null`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!airline) return;

  fetch(`${url}${airline.hubIataCode}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setAirport(data));
}, [airline]);
```

Option 2 - combine requests to a single `useEffect` using async/await:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const [airline] = await sanityClient.fetch(`*[slug.current == $slug]{...hubIataCode,...}`, { slug });
      const airport = await fetch(`${url}${airline.hubIataCode}`).then((response) => response.json());
      setAirline(airline);
      setAirport(airport);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
  
  fetchData();
}, [slug]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I went for option 2 and it works perfectly. Why does airline need square braces, by the way?

Comment: Because airline is `data[0]` (the 1st element of an array). I use destructuring the get it directly instead of `const data = await sanityClient.fetch(...); const airline = data[0];`.

Comment: Actually, I am getting `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'airport.nameAirport')` (or any other field from the response). It was working the first time I rendered the page but now it isn't. Perhaps it isn't waiting for the data still?

Comment: The 1st render would use `null` for `airport` so you should probably guard again that, for example `if(!airport) return null;` before you return JSX, or use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) - `airport?.nameAirport`.

Comment: I do have `if (!airline) return <Loading />` but the page just infinitely tries to render with `TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...[airport]...')` in the console. I thought that it would wait for the IATA code from the first fetch before doing the second fetch and then render, but it appears it doesn't do that?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't. You'll need to create a live codesandbox or similar, because I don't have any other guesses :)

Comment: It's okay, it was a typo! My mistake and all working fine. Thanks for all your help.